# creating radio buttons from a loop and select all in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am looking for a way to select all the radio buttons in one go using action button. In below example, radio buttons (Yes,No) are created using loop. Now, there are two buttons -" YES SELECT ALL" and "NO SELECT ALL", Now based on " YES SELECT ALL" Button click **all Yes option** of radio buttons are selected. Same goes for "NO SELECT ALL" button. Looking a way to achieve the same.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
title = 'Creating a UI from a loop',

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(

  lapply(1:5, function(i) {
    selectInput(paste0('a', i), paste0('SelectA', i),
                choices = sample(LETTERS, 5))
  })
),

mainPanel(
  verbatimTextOutput('a_out'),

  br(),

  uiOutput("c_ui"),

  br(),

  actionButton("yesall","YES ALL SELECT"),
  actionButton("noall","NO ALL SELECT"),

  br(),


  lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    uiOutput(paste0('b', i))
  })
)
)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$a_out <- renderPrint({
res <- lapply(1:5, function(i) input[[paste0('a', i)]])
str(setNames(res, paste0('a', 1:5)))
})

lapply(1:10, function(i) {
output[[paste0('b', i)]] <- renderUI({
  strong(paste0('Hi, this is output B#', i))
})
})

output$c_ui  <- renderUI({

lapply(1:5, function(i) {

  radioButtons(paste0('c', i), label = "",choices = list("Yes" = "yes", "No" = "may be"),selected = character(0),inline = TRUE)

})

})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Creating a UI from a loop',

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      lapply(1:5, function(i) {
        selectInput(paste0('a', i), paste0('SelectA', i),
                    choices = sample(LETTERS, 5))
      })
    ),

    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput('a_out'),

      br(),

      uiOutput("c_ui"),

      br(),

      actionButton("yesall","YES ALL SELECT"),
      actionButton("noall","NO ALL SELECT"),

      br(),


      lapply(1:10, function(i) {
        uiOutput(paste0('b', i))
      })
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$a_out <- renderPrint({
    res <- lapply(1:5, function(i) input[[paste0('a', i)]])
    str(setNames(res, paste0('a', 1:5)))
  })

  lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    output[[paste0('b', i)]] <- renderUI({
      strong(paste0('Hi, this is output B#', i))
    })
  })

  output$c_ui  <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
      radioButtons(paste0('c', i), label = "",choices = list("Yes" = "yes", "No" = "may be"),selected = character(0),inline = T)
    })
  })


  observeEvent(input$yesall,{
    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
      updateRadioButtons(session,paste0('c', i), label = "",choices = list("Yes" = "yes", "No" = "may be"),selected = "yes",inline = T)
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$noall,{
    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
      updateRadioButtons(session,paste0('c', i), label = "",choices = list("Yes" = "yes", "No" = "may be"),selected = "may be",inline = T)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]